# Clear panel from usercontrol C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, event-handling, panel

I have a panel in a form and 2 UserControl, When the form loads, in the load () method, loads the first usercontrol using this code:

```
private void OlvidadaContraseña_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    UserControl1 Env = new UserControl1();
    panel1.Controls.Add(Env);
}
```

How can I clean the panel (form panel) and load the second usercontrol from the first usercontrol?(Access form control from the usercontrol?)

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

if you want change clean panel and load other usercontrol with first usercontrol you must use delegate-event. 
you mast add on control (button,..) in first usercontrol

in code behind first userControl :

```
public partial class EnvioContraseña: UserControl
{
    public delegate void LoadOtherUserControl(EnvioContraseña sender);
    public event LoadOtherUserControl On_SelectButton;
    public EnvioContraseña()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (On_SelectButton != null)
            On_SelectButton(this);
    }
}
```

then in code behind mainform

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        EnvioContraseña Env = new EnvioContraseña ();
        Env.On_SelectButton += Env_On_SelectButton;
        panel1.Controls.Add(Env);
    }

    void Env_On_SelectButton(EnvioContraseña sender)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);
    }
```

Comment: How can I use the delegate-event in this example?